# SBT custom conflict manager

Tags: sbt, dependency-management

I would like to get a better idea of conflicting dependencies between artifacts in my organization. For this, I have created a meta-project that includes all the other top-level projects. To identify conflicts of various transitive dependencies, my idea was to use a conflict manager.

I know I can set a conflict manager like this

```
conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict
```

1. How would I set the strict manager only for `com.example` packages, and possibly compose it with other more specific managers?
2. Is it possible to create completely custom dependency managers, which would only warn about conflicts?

I am also thankful for other ideas on solving this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can do it with

   `conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict.copy(organization = "com.example.*")`

   You can vary (Ivy) type of conflict manager, organization and module filters. See this sbt [source with it's definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/sbt/IvyInterface.scala.html#sbt;ConflictManager). Also see Ivy [docs on types of conflict managers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/conflict-managers.html)
2. It seems that you can define a custom Ivy conflict manager setting it's name with `ConflictManager("...")` (see the Ivy docs on what you can to write there). Although I don't see any way to combine several  conflict managers: sbt provides only one setting key `conflictManager` and sets the ivy manager [directly from it](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.1/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Ivy.scala#L426).